# All of a sudden getting an error in Google Sheets from this function that existed for years. Did they change something recently?

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a function a while ago to determine if a sheet in a workbook already exists. Here is the function:

```
function SheetNameExists(name){
  return (ActiveSpreadSheet().getSheetByName(name).toString().indexOf(name) != 0);
}
```

All of a sudden within the last month or so I get a `TypeError: Cannot call method "toString" of null. (line 105, file "Code")`. Line 105 is the `return` statement.

Up until this error started happening I have had no issues with any of the scripts on this Sheet. I did not change anything in the code-behind.

Did Google change up something without providing deprecation support?

---

EDIT: I forgot `ActiveSpreadsheet()` was not a built-in function when I wrote all this out. This is the code I wrote to get it:

```
function ActiveSpreadSheet(){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
}
```

Comment: I think that the error indicates that ``ActiveSpreadSheet().getSheetByName(name)`` returns ``null``. So please confirm whether there is the sheet name of ``name`` in the Spreadsheet, again. And in your case, ``ActiveSpreadSheet().getSheetByName(name).toString()`` returns ``Sheet`` for various values of ``name``. So I think that at ``ActiveSpreadSheet().getSheetByName(name).toString().indexOf(name) != 0``, only when ``name`` is ``Sheet``, it becomes ``false``.

Comment: I've used this sheet and the functions flawlessly for almost 4 years now. I can post the full code-behind if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, how about creating new spreadsheet and copying the values, sheets and the script, and then, running the script? If that was not the solution, in order to confirm your situation, can you provide a sample spreadsheet including the script for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your private information.

Comment: There are probably only a few of reasons why `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` would fail.  1) The code is being run many times in rapid succession, and a quota limit is being hit 2) The script project is not bound to a Sheet 3) Google servers had a service outage.  4) Maybe the permissions changed?   `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` is used a lot.  If there was a service outage on Google's servers, there would be at least thousands of people complaining that their code didn't work any more.  Does anyone else have access to the Sheet?  Have you removed an permissions recently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I question how this could have worked before.  getSheetByName(name) will return a Sheet object. toString() simply returns the string "Sheet".  So it will only match name if name is "Sheet".  However your problem is quite simple.

```
var active = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  // For sure the active spreadsheet
var sheet = active.getSheetByName(name);  // Where name is a string representing a sheet name
if( sheet ) return true;  // Sheet with name exists
return false;  // Other wise sheet is null or does not exist
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! I changed the function that was getting an error to the following: `function SheetNameExists(name){
  return ActiveSheetByName(name);  
}`. The `ActiveSheetByName()` function just does what your second line does. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't know of any method ActiveSheetByName.  It must be a function you have in your project.  My method is vanilla SpreadsheetApp.

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention that I made a custom function I put in my code so I did not have to write out `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name);` since I called that several times. My fault.